# What does it exactly mean when a function f is meromorphic at infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms

Then does the function have a pole at infinity , or does it mean there is a neighborhood N of infinity so that there are points contained in N which are poles of f ?

If a function f  is modular , it also means that it is meromorphic at infinity .

Does this mean that f does not need to have a pole at infinity ?

Comment: Well no for a modular form meromorphic at $i\infty$ means $f(\frac{\log q}{2i\pi})$ is meromorphic at $q=0$. Since $f(z)$ is defined only on $\Im(z) > 0$ it is never meromorphic at $\infty$.

Comment: It means that  $f$ has a pole or a removable singularity at infinity.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f(z)$ meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ can be extended to a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{P}^1$ if in a neighborhood of "infinity" is meromorphic, that is, it could have a pole or not, but it does NOT have an essential singularity. This is equivalent to say that the function $f(\frac{1}{z})$ is meromorphic at zero.
For example, any polynomial can be extended to a meromorphic function at infinity. BUT, I leave to you to prove that $e^z$ CAN'T be meromorphic at infinity.

Comment: I don't know, how do you define a function to be meromorphic at infinity if not by $\mathbb{P}^1$? Just saying that it must have limit at infinity? Thanks for the feedback, anyway.

Comment: If $f$ is meromorphic on $\Bbb{C}$ with infinitely many poles then $\infty$ is not an isolated singularity. In general $f$ can have infinitely many singularities of any kind, $f$ meromorphic at $\infty$ means $f(1/z)$ is meromorphic at $0$. The motivation is that from the chart $\phi(z)= 1/z$ the Riemann sphere $\Bbb{C}\cup \infty$ becomes a Riemann surface.